# Functions in where clause - BQ

Tags: sql, performance, google-bigquery

I have always avoided to use functions in the WHERE or ON clauses.

However, I am now working with Big Query and I wonder whether is the same that in the "old" data warehouses as it doesn't have indexes.
I still avoid it but I am doing code reviews where I see this and I don't really know if using a function in a WHERE will affect anything else apart from me.

Does anyone know about it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery is a massively parallel database.  Basically, the generic equi-join algorithm is going to partitioning on the key values and send the rows from both tables -- with the same key -- to the same node.  And whether the key is a column or a function result adds little overhead beyond the actual function call.

This actually works pretty well even if you are using functions.  For instance, I have found that sometimes I need to compare strings and integers -- say, when using an id value embedded in a string.  This requires conversion and that has reasonable performance.

So, I would say that what you learned about function calls affecting indexes is true.  But there are no indexes in BQ so that isn't a concern.  Of course, expensive function calls can be an issue.  And function calls can impede partition pruning.  So they can have an effect.